# What settings does Visual Studio 2012 require to print the Kernel debug messages?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-studio-2012, device-driver

Host Win7_x64, target VM Win7_x64 both on same physical machine.
Driver debugging using VS 2012 (Visual Studio Integrated Windows Debugger.)

Able to provisioning between Host and target using VS 2012 and WDK 8.0.

KmdfSmall driver given on msdn is properly able to install on target VM; showing into Device Manager as well on target VM, as posted in my last query.

when ever I'm pressing F5, 'Debugger Immediate Window' in VS 2012 also showing 'breakpoint hit' and as I mentioned earlier in my msg, return value of KdPrintEx is also correct i.e. STATUS_SUCCESS.

Do I missing some setting into VS 2012 to display the msg's of "KdPrintEx". Means why my `KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "\n KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd has been called\n"))` is not printing any msg's into 'Debugger Immediate Window'.

Answer (score 0):

`KdPrintEx` has no effect in release configuration, make sure to compile in debug mode or use `DbgPrintEx`.

Answer (score 0):

changed the value of Component Filter Mask on target machine where driver has been installed to debug.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter.

Under this key, created a value with the name "IHVDRIVER" and Set the value of this key equal to the DWORD value 0x8".

I choose "IHVDRIVER" because in my KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_"IHVDRIVER"_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "\n KmdfSmallEvtDeviceAdd has been called\n"))
And DWORD value 0x8 because Leveling.

For detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519(v=vs.85).aspx

thanks you

regards
matt